# Visual Studio F12 Navigates to MetaData. Web App vs Web Site

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

There is a difference in behavior of the F12 function in Visual Studio. This affects VS 2012 and 2017 (other versions not tested). The problem appeared after years of working as expected. I've done my best to document the problem in hopes of finding a solution. I've created a dummy solution to document the problem.

The setup:

A simple VS solution with 2 projects. A Web **Application** and a Web **Site** project. Each project contains 1 form and 1 user control.

[image]

The Web **Application** form contains a user control with a function call.

[image]

Hitting F12 navigates to the function definition.

[image]

The Web **Site** form also contains a user control with a function call.

[image]

Hitting F12 navigates to the **MetaData** instead of the **function definition**.

[image]

This affects all projects, and at the very least VS 2012 & VS 2017. This change in behaviour occurred without warning.

I've already attempted:

- Reset VS user settings
- Reinstall VS completely
- Repairing .NET framework
- Clearing ASP.net temp folder
- Using VS extension (F12 GoTo Definition)
- Many other posted solutions

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this sometimes works for me:

- close all VS instances
- delete all obj/bin directories in your solution
- delete all *.suo and *proj.user files